# SQL query output using group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this view in an Oracle db and I'm trying to generate a report with an SQL query but it's not working for last few days now so decide to get expert advice.

View does runs well. Basically what view does is it records all users who log into any database for auditing purpose.

View columns:

- dbname
- username
- server
- program
- logon_time

Questions:

1. I am trying to generate SQL to group by all username and program who log in to dbname=x on date=26-Dec-2012
2. count distinct username and program where user logged on 26-Dec-2012

Basically trying to get... if dbname=x get 50000 login via username=abc then abc was connected from which server and what program?

Tried the following query

```
  select dbname, username, server, program, logon_time from audit 
    where username = abc and 
    dbname in (select dbname from audit
       where dbname='x' and logon_time = to_date('26-DEC-2012','DD-MON-YYY')) 
         group by username, program
```

Comment: what did you try? any query you wrote not working?

Comment: Why is the view not given a name in the question?  It's hard to reference the anonymous!

Comment: thanks for quick comments... view name is Audit   I have tried select dbname, username, server, program, logon_time from audit where username = abc and dbname in (select dbname from audit where dbname='x' and logon_time = to_date('26-DEC-2012','DD-MON-YYY')) group by username, program;       Note: tried to place query properly but everytime I press enter it was submitting my comments

Comment: In the future, please update your question with this information ;-) . good luck.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems very straight-forward, except for issues with [reformatting the date+time information](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_date_format.jsp) into just date information.

Query 1:

```
SELECT username, program
  FROM Audit
 WHERE dbname = 'x'
   AND TO_CHAR(logon_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2012-12-26'
 GROUP BY username, program;
```

This should give you a list of the distinct username, program combinations that logged into database `'x'` on 26th December 2012.

Query 2:

You want the COUNT of the rows from Query 1 except for the criterion about database name, so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT username, program
          FROM Audit
         WHERE TO_CHAR(logon_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2012-12-26'
         GROUP BY username, program
       )
```

This should give you a count of the distinct user name, program combinations that connected to any database on 26th December 2012.

Comment: thank you very much it does work as expected, gives detailed count of users logged in.                                                          @ Gerrat you query also works well if I don't user date in query but it give total counts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT dbname, username, server, program, trunc(logon_time), count(*) FROM audit 
WHERE username = 'abc'
AND dbname = 'x' 
AND logon_time >= to_date('26-DEC-2012','DD-MON-YYY')
AND logon_time < to_date('27-DEC-2012','DD-MON-YYY')
GROUP BY dbname, username, server, program, trunc(logon_time)
```

**Edit:** Answer revised to fix grouping mistake Conrad pointed out.
Still not 100% sure what is required, but this should be much closer.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. What if the records are are `{server='abc',login_time = '12:00 PM'}` and `{server = 'zbc', login_time ='8:00 AM'}` Your output would show `{server='abc', login_time = '8:00 AM'}` giving the impression that user logged into abc at 8:00 which isn't correct

Comment: @Gerrat  thank you for your efforts somehow '0' rows were selected, trying few other workarounds with the help of your query. I noticed whenever I was using date in filter part it either gives me 1 row or no row.

Comment: @Conrad:  You're right. He asked to group by username, program but that isn't exactly what he wants.  I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Basically trying simple output report with counts or list like  <br/> 1. user 'ABC' logged 500 times on DB'x' with program 'XYZ'  <br/>  2. user 'ABC' logged 100 times on DB 'X' with program 'ZYX'

Comment: @conrad unfortunately no rows selected.

Comment: THANK YOU sincerely all experts who viewed, answered and commented on this post.